# EF Core: Update FK while Navigation Property is loaded

Tags: entity-framework-core

Consider the following class, consisting of a foreign key and a corresponding navigation property.

```
class MyClass
{
    public long FkId { get; set; }
    public MyOtherClass FkNavigationProperty { get; set; }
}
```

My update problem

```
MyClass myUpdate =
    new MyClass
    {
        FkId = 5, //the new value which i want to save
        FkNavigationProperty = new MyOtherClass { Id = 3 } //the old value that was loaded with the entity
    }

context.Update(myUpdate);
context.SaveChanges();
```

**The Problem**

This leads to a saved MyClass Entity with FK value of 3 instead of the desired 5.

**Why do I have this problem**

Normally, I would make sure, that no navigation property is loaded on the updated entity.
But currently, this is impossible to make sure.

**What I would like to know**

What are the best practices for such situations?

1. Setting the navigation property to null and set only the foreign key id?
2. Set both, the foreign key id in on the entity and in the navigation property?
3. Load the desired foreign key entity and set it into the navigation property (leaving the foreign key on the old value)?
4. Other propositions?
5. *EDIT: is it always the case, that navigation property "wins" over foreign key property? (if yes, is this documented somewhere?)*

Thanks for any help with this!

Cheers, Mike